# MySQL how to get the time difference, if second argument is NULL by using TIMESTAMPDIFF?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contain fail time and the corresponding start time of several machines to track their downtime.

```
machine_status(
id integer auto_increment,
machine_no integer,
fail_time datetime,
start_time datetime)
```

I am able to get the total downtime of each machine with

```
SELECT machine_no, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, fail_time, start_time)) duration
from machine_status
GROUP BY machine_no
```

But, if a machine is down at the moment of executing the query `start_time` is NULL. In this case I want to substitute current timestamp to `start_time` and then get the time difference.

Basically how can I do something like this?

```
SELECT machine_no, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, fail_time, 
IF start_time IS NULL THEN NOW() ELSE start_time)) duration
from machine_status
GROUP BY machine_no
```

Comment: you could try replace `IF start_time IS NULL THEN NOW() ELSE start_time` by `IFNULL(start_time, NOW())`

Comment: Thanks [Antony](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2250843/antony-gibbs). It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job

```
SELECT
  ms.machine_no AS machine_no,
  SUM(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, ms.fail_time, IFNULL(ms.start_time, NOW()) )
  ) AS duration
FROM machine_status AS ms
GROUP BY ms.machine_no
```

Comment: This will not work as expected. The replacement will only be made if there is only one row for a machine and its start_time is null. If you have a previous outage for a machine that is currently down, its reported down time will be way too high.

Comment: I'm not sure about this.  But I'd say it's worth checking with some test data

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
    SELECT 
        machine_no, 
        SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, fail_time, IFNULL(start_time, NOW()))) AS duration
    FROM machine_status
    GROUP BY machine_no
```

Comment: Your answer worked. And thank you so much. I've accepted [Antony](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2250843/antony-gibbs)'s answer since he suggested this first.